# jquery how to hide <select> menu

Tags: jquery, select, hide

```
    <select id="wybierz1" style="display:none" >
      <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="top" style="display:none" >- SELECT -</option >
    </select>
```

the above display:none does not work. I have also tried "hidden", but to no avail.

How to hide this select menu?

Comment: Seems hidden to me: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FvBza/

Comment: Can you please prove it in a fiddle.

Comment: Do you know what is the meaning of `display: none;`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tearex/vytwm/
with jquery switched on, it does not hide.

Comment: If you used css file with rule for this select box, look if you have not !important for display there.

Answer (score 3):

wrap `<select>` with `<div>` or `<span>` and add id to tag.

```
<span id="wybierz1"><select>
  <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="top" style="display:none" >- SELECT -</option >
</select></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, a sure-fire way is to do this:

```
$('#wybierz1').hide();
```

Although, you really do not need jQuery for this, as CSS should be sufficient.

Comment: well, style="display:none" is css. 
as for $('#wybierz1').hide(), I have tested it - it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use jQuery, because it's jQuery Mobile that is causing the issue I believe. Here are two identical scripts, but one has jQuery loaded.

Working: jsfiddle.net/j08691/FvBza

Not Working(jquery mobile): jsfiddle.net/tearex/vytwm

You can find the answer to your question here: [JQuery show/hide in JQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213345/jquery-show-hide-in-jquery-mobile) 
or here: 
[Cannot hide/show elements in jQuery Mobile application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219018/cannot-hide-show-elements-in-jquery-mobile-application)

Comment: It is a bigger app for mobile platforms, so I will stick with jqm. I guess, i will wrap the select in a div. already checked, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#wybierz1').parent().hide();` to hide the select menu